# What Causes These Two Different Shades of the Same Color?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, color, pspicture

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\definecolor{darkpurple}{RGB}{48, 25, 52}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\psframe[fillcolor=darkpurple,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12)
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which, when compiled with `xelatex`, produces

[image]

Now, consider the code (which invokes the same color as the previous code)

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 8.5in \textwidth 5.75in 
\usepackage{xcolor}


\definecolor{darkpurple}{RGB}{48, 25, 52}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, calc}
\tikzfading[name=dim fade, inner color=transparent!40, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!100, middle color=transparent!0]
\tikzfading[name=long bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!0]

\newcommand{\glowstar}[3][.5]{\fill[white,path fading=dim fade](#2)circle[radius=#1*.6];
    \foreach \t in {0,60,120}{
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.05*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.02*#1)$)--cycle;
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=long bright fade]($(#2)-(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.04*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.04*#1)$)--cycle;
    }
    \foreach \l [count=\n from 0] in {#3}{
        \fill[rotate around={\n*90:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(\l*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(.4,.06*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.4,.06*#1)$)--cycle;
     }        
    \fill[white] (#2)circle[radius=#1*.13];
    }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[darkpurple] rectangle (16,12);
\glowstar[1.8]{8,8}{1,1,1,1}% length of left,bottom,right,top
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which, when compiled with `pdflatex`, produces the output

[image]

However, when I use a snipping tool to cut out a rectangle (containing the star) and superimpose it on the `pspicture` generated by the first code, one can easily see that the "same" shade of purple used in both codes is not quite the same. The following picture was compiled with `xelatex` after snipping the glowing star image with an online tool and inserting it into the code as `includegraphics`---

[image]

QUESTION: What has caused this phenomenon of two different shades of the same color? Has `xelatex` and `pdflatex` produced two different hues of the same RGB color; or, could the problem be with the online snipping tool I use?

REMARK: I know that if I actually wanted to impose the star image on the first pspicture, it is possible to compile the code directly and compile everything with `xelatex`---but, I would like to know what is causing the two different hues of purple generated by the same RGB formula. If I change the color, the same phenomenon occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess #1 for the culprit  is the color management of your screen and/or the program used to preview the image. Are you cutting and pasting on the same screen?. Have you tried a color picker to check the real RGB value on screen?

Comment: I guess pstricks ≠ TikZ.

Comment: (also did you try compiling the second code with XeLaTeX as well?)

Comment: Both the first and second (standalone) patch say 48, 25, 52 here with a color picker. In the combined one, the darker part is 41, 20, 44 --- so there is something pesky in the combining, like a transparency effect.

Comment: @Rmano The last picture was compiled with `xelatex` after inserting the cut-out image as `includegraphics`.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear at all. Something is pesky there, so; you should add the last piece of MWE... but yes, it's puzzling.

Comment: Many thanks @Rmano

Comment: My guess is that when you snip and save the image, you are saving it with a colour profile. If I'm careful to save the star image without a colour profile then the colours match exactly.

Comment: Many thanks for this information @DavidPurton